Ubuntu gets stuck at boot and recovery doesn't load
I have a Ubuntu system which is not booting up. After the grub the Ubuntu logo comes up and freezes at this screen or reboots again after sometime.

So I thought it could be a grub problem of something that can be resolved with recovery. But the recovery also does not load, when I select recovery mode under Advanced grub options, the following screen loads for a while and it also freezes, and the recovery menu never shows up.

So then I tried to boot a live iso, Ubuntu and Gparted, both does the same after the grub menu they freezes or reboots and I get this error some times.

I have also reset the BIOS and even updated it to a latest release by Gigabyte and now I have no idea what is going wrong.

see this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1522294/1698042

@guiverc It is Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, it's a dual boot but the 2nd OS is in another drive and no changes were made to the 2nd OS. My primary Ubuntu, I think was updating and my motherboard crashed for something and I had to get it repaired.

The problem was with the CPU, I had to change it. Things working fine now.
